List in macOS tray app displays strangely
My Code is very simple.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack {
                
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.red)
            
        }.frame(width: 320, height: 400)
    }
}

This code shows normal as below:

If I change the inner ZStack to List, like this below:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<10) { index in
                    Text("Index-\(index)")
                }
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 100)
        }.frame(width: 320, height: 400)
    }
}

The top triangle is gone and the popover's location is strange.

I want to know how to fix this issue.
Some other code:
@main
struct VeryToDoApp: App {
    
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor var delegate: AppDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem!
    var popover: NSPopover!
    
    override init() {
        
    }
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        setupStatusBarItem()
        setupPopover()
    }
    
    func setupStatusBarItem() {
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            let imageSize = NSSize(width: 22, height: 22)
            button.image = NSImage(named: "AppIcon")
            button.image?.size = imageSize
            button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
        }
    }
    
    func setupPopover() {
        popover = NSPopover()
        popover.behavior = .transient
        popover.contentViewController = PopoverViewController().makeNSViewController()
    }
    
    @objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        if popover.isShown {
            closePopover(sender)
        } else {
            showPopover(sender)
        }
    }
    
    func showPopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
        }
    }
    
    func closePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        popover.performClose(sender)
    }
    
}

struct PopoverViewController: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> NSViewController {
        return makeNSViewController()
    }
    
    func makeNSViewController() -> NSViewController {
        let viewController = NSViewController()
        viewController.view = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: NSViewController, context: Context) {
        // Update code if needed
    }
}


Use SwiftUI’s native MenuBarExtra with .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
import SwiftUI

@main
struct HelloMenuBarApp: App {
    private let animals = ["Lions", "Tigers", "Bears"]
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        MenuBarExtra {
            List {
                ForEach(animals, id: \.self) { animal in
                   Text(animal)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 320, height: 400)
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "tray.2.fill")
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}


It works, and gives another style pop out window. Another question: The pop out window shows left align to the tray icon, not center

Correct. It uses the native Menu Bar Extra per Apple’s Human Interface Guidelines documented here: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/the-menu-bar#Menu-bar-extras
Assuming you want an NSPopOver to host a SwiftUI view — instead of, say, other AppKit API — then maybe you could achieve the same effect by using the .background() modifier instead of a ZStack?
Other things to try:

Add or modify ZStack(alignment: .top)
Change List.frame(height:) to List.frame(maxHeight:)
Remove .frame() from the list

